# handling Java unchecked exceptions

Tags: java

I have a Java program where users are prompted to enter two integers, x and y. The program then performs the division x/y and prints the result. If either x is out of the array bounds or y is zero, the user is asked to re-enter both x and y, regardless of which condition is violated.

However, I want to refine this behavior so that if only y is incorrect (e.g., y is zero), the program should only ask the user to re-enter y, not both x and y.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try {

    static int[] T = {17, 12, 15, 38, 29, 157, 89, -22, 0, 5};

    static int div(int index, int divider) {
        return T[index] / divider;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("index : ");
                int x = sc.nextInt();
                if (x < 0 || x >= T.length) {
                    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
                }

                int y;
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("devider: ");
                    y = sc.nextInt();
                    if (y != 0) {
                        break; // Break the loop if y is not zero
                    }
                    System.out.println("Enter a devider different than Zero\n");
                }

                System.out.println("\n result: " + div(x, y));
                break; // Break the outer loop if the division is successful
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("Division by zero is not allowed\n");
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and " + (T.length - 1) + "\n");
            } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter a number\n");
                sc.nextLine(); // Consume the invalid input
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify my code so that it only asks the user to re-enter y when it's incorrect, while still ensuring that x is within the array bounds?

Comment: What is the problem you are struggling with? Currently you always ask for `x` and `y` when your `try` block is called. There is no alternate execution path.

Comment: @Progman when the user enters a correct value for x but a wrong one for y  instead of asking them to only re-enter y and then print the result its asks them for x and then y and then prints the result

Comment: At the moment your question is very hard to read because you've put all of it as a single sentence. Try reading it through to yourself - how easily are you able to understand it? Please take some time to edit the question to make it much easier to understand.

Comment: Okay, so that's a bit clearer - but it's not clear why you're deliberately throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for `x`, rather than using the same kind of loop that you are for `y`...

Answer (score 1):

It ask X again because you are looping both variable acquisition in the same block. if you want to read only the wrong variable you have to separate reading or check before reading. In any case, you don't really need to throw an exception manually, all cases can be handle with `if` blocks.

this is the code that check if a parameter is readed correctly and then do the thing.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try {
    static int[] T = {17, 12, 15, 38, 29, 157, 89, -22, 0, 5};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int indice = -1, diviseur = 0; // set variables with wrong value, to check
        boolean termine = false;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!termine) {
            if (indice < 0 || indice >= T.length) {
                System.out.println("l’indice de l’entier à diviser: ");
                indice = sc.nextInt();
                if (indice < 0 || indice >= T.length) {
                    // System.out.println(m.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Entrez un indice entre 0 et " + (T.length - 1) + "\n");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
            } else if (diviseur == 0) {
                System.out.println("le diviseur: ");
                diviseur = sc.nextInt();
                if (diviseur == 0) {
                    // System.out.println(s.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Entrez un diviseur différent de zéro\n");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nLe résultat de la division est: " + div(indice, diviseur));
                termine = true;
            }
        }
    }

    static int div(int indice, int diviseur) {
        return T[indice] / diviseur;
    }
}
```

or do it in two separate loops

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Try {
    static int[] T = {17, 12, 15, 38, 29, 157, 89, -22, 0, 5};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int indice = -1, diviseur = 0; // set variables with wrong value, to check

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (indice < 0 || indice >= T.length) {
            System.out.println("l’indice de l’entier à diviser: ");
            indice = sc.nextInt();
            if (indice < 0 || indice >= T.length) {
                // System.out.println(m.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Entrez un indice entre 0 et " + (T.length - 1) + "\n");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
        while (diviseur == 0) {
            System.out.println("le diviseur: ");
            diviseur = sc.nextInt();
            if (diviseur == 0) {
                // System.out.println(s.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Entrez un diviseur différent de zéro\n");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nLe résultat de la division est: " + div(indice, diviseur));
    }


    static int div(int indice, int diviseur) {
        return T[indice] / diviseur;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kika <3 if is it, please take a sec to check my answer, <3 really appreciated !